# Print a string (up to 10 chars) as a diamond

Tags: java, string

**I need to print a string (up to 10 chars) as a diamond.**

Well, I tried for almost 2-3 hours now to solve it and I'm still having many problems.

Here's the code: it works for outputs 'a', 'abc', 'abcde'. which means only works for strings with length of 1,3,5. and also, it only prints the first half of the diamond.

Any help is highly appreciated.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class MyFirstClass1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int halfSize;
        int p = 0;
        String message;
        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        message = input.nextLine();
        //System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(message.length() / 2) + 1);
        halfSize = message.length() / 2;
         for (int i = 1; i <= message.length(); i++) {
             //Print spaces
              for (int k = 0; k < halfSize; k++)
                System.out.print(" ");
              halfSize--;

              System.out.print("\n");

              if((int)Math.ceil((float)message.length() / 2) + 1 >= p)
              {
              for (int j = 0; j < p + 1; j++)
                  System.out.print(message.charAt(j));
              }
              p+=2;
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: It wil be very helpful if you describe what is the input and the output you need to get.

Comment: What is `p` supposed to be? What is `(int)Math.ceil(message.length() / 2) + 1` supposed to be? Why are you printing spaces only on the first blank line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were lot of logical errors. I have fixed them. This is working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    int halfSize;
    int p = 0;
    String message;
    System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    message = input.nextLine();
    halfSize = 2 * message.length() - 1;

     for (int i = 1; i <= message.length(); i++) {
         int pre_post_blank = (2 * halfSize) - ( 2 * i -1);

          for (int k = 0; k < pre_post_blank / 2; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");


          for(int j = 0; j < i;j++ )
          {
              System.out.print(message.charAt(j));
              System.out.print(" ");
          }



          for (int k = 0; k < pre_post_blank / 2; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");

          System.out.print("\n");
       }
       for (int i = message.length(); i >= 1; i--) {
         int pre_post_blank = (2 * halfSize) - ( 2 * i -1);

          for (int k = 0; k < pre_post_blank / 2; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");


          for(int j = 0; j < i;j++ )
          {
              System.out.print(message.charAt(j));
              System.out.print(" ");
          }



          for (int k = 0; k < pre_post_blank / 2; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");

          System.out.print("\n");
       }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The below should help

```
    int halfSize;
    int p = 0;
    boolean is_bottom;
    String message;
    // System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
    // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    message = "12345";
    is_bottom = false;

    //System.out.println((int)Math.ceil(message.length() / 2) + 1);
    halfSize = message.length() / 2;
     for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
         //Print spaces
          for (int j = 0; j < message.length(); j++) {
            if (j == halfSize || (j <= (halfSize + p) && j >= (halfSize - p)))
              System.out.print(message.charAt(j));
              else
              System.out.print("*");
          }

          if (is_bottom == false) {
        if (p >= halfSize)
        is_bottom = true;
       }

       if (is_bottom == false)
       p++;
       else
       p--;

       System.out.println();
       }
```

`I` is the rows
`j` is the columns
and the if statement is your main logic to print the characters in the right location

I added a static string for the message so you can see the result faster, just uncomment your code to ask for input.

Also make sure to do a check that the length of the string is an odd number, if not then throw an error message stating that it is an invalid string

It is much faster and neater and easier to understand than to have many for loops and if statements. :) hope you enjoy java as much as I did

Answer (score 0):

I think the code may be easier to read if you use a recursive function here. That will also be a good learning exercise for you to understand recursion. Like so:

```
public static void printDiamond(String message) {
    diamondAbove(message, " ");
    System.out.println(message);
    diamondBelow(message, " ");
}
public static void diamondAbove(String below, String padding) {
    if(below.length() > 2) {
        String current = below.substring(0, below.length()-2);
        diamondAbove(current, padding + " ");
        System.out.println(padding + current);
    }
}
public static void diamondBelow(String above, String padding) {
    if(above.length() > 2) {
        String current = above.substring(0, above.length()-2);
        System.out.println(padding + current);
        diamondBelow(current, padding + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: as you wrote yourself - "this is a newbie who is struggling to write his first class in java" so I don't think that recursion is the right approach if you really want to help him...

Comment: @TDG judge for yourself which is easier to read. I have been staring at some of these iterative solutions for a while now and still not entirely sure what they are doing or trying to do.

Comment: also, recursion is not exactly an advanced topic. that is standard fare for newbie intro to comp. sci courses.